# Can not access the value of a Calculated column inside my power-shell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, powershell, administration, 2016

I am working on sharepoint 2016 on-premises farm. and i wrote the following power-shell script to update the items of a list:-

```
>>  $web = get-spweb "http://servername/offices/Departments/IT/"
>>  $list2 = $web.lists["list123"]
>> foreach ($i in $list2.items)
>> {
>> $a = $i["ID"];
>>
>> $sourceItem = $list2.items.GetItemById($a);
>>
>> $sourceItem["NormalNumericColumn"] = $sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"] ;
;
>>
>> $sourceItem.Systemupdate();
>>
>>
>> }
>>
```

where what i am trying to achieve to to assign a normal numeric field, the value of a calculated column (which is also of type number). but the above script will raise the following exception:-

```
Exception calling "SystemUpdate" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid number value.
A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."
At line:15 char:1
+ $sourceItem.Systemupdate();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

now if i try to get the value for a non-calculated column, the script will work fine.. so can anyone adivce if there is a way to the value for a calculated column inside my power-shell script ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculated field, even if defined as a number, isn't a full number - it's structured almost like a lookup - there a float;# in front of it.

You can do a .split(';#')[1] to get the value. It will have decimal values, 2 will show up as 2.0000000000000, so you might have to deal with that..

Comment: @Robim seems your answer was correct we will get the value as follow "float;#123.00000" so we need to use split

Comment: my calculated field value is "string;#Yes" but I need to use .split(';#')[2] to get the "Yes" value. I will get empty value for [1]. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if($sourceItem){
    $cf = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCalculated]$list2.Fields["CalcualtedNumericColumn"];
    $cf.GetFieldValueAsText($sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"]) //should output value
    }
```

Comment: thanks foer the reply now the 2 columns the calculated + the number column are of type number with automatic number of decimals.. so i need to parse the value is this correct? should i parse the calculated column to double ?

Comment: yes! just parse to double, then use it

Comment: now i tried this but i am getting this error "you not call the method on a null-valued expression.."  and non of the fields got updated

Comment: if you type in `$sourceItem` instead for that line, does it return something?

Comment: can you advice what do you mean exactly please?

Comment: try my edit, should run only if `$sourceItem` is found.

Comment: now i run this as a test  `$web = get-spweb "http://servername/offices/Dubai/Departments/IT/"
$list2 = $web.lists["b2"]
foreach ($i in $list2.items)
{
$a = $i["ID"];

$sourceItem = $list2.items.GetItemById($a);
Write-Host $sourceItem.Title
}`

Comment: and i got the items titles correctly..

Comment: try `Write-host $sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"]`

Comment: i got weird values with hash & commas as follow "float;#123.00000"

Comment: then try `$value = [double] $sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"].toString().Split('#')[1]`

Comment: now i got the correct numbers. but not sure why when i copy/paste the following from my notepad to powershell `.toString().Split('#')‌​[1];` it will be entered as follow `.toString().Split('#')‌​??[1];` so not sure why ?? is added !!

Comment: not sure, but glad it works, sometimes you have to retype in powershell because the character mapping is different

Comment: so now i do not have to use $cf.GetFieldValueAsText() or doing parsing [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCalculated] ... i just need to do a split of the row value??

Comment: If you have the value, you won't need that anymore, just assign that value to  the other column as you were doing before. `$sourceItem["NormalNumericColumn"] = [double] $sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"].toString().Split('#')‌​[1];`

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, it is basically get the value of Calculated filed as text then convert it to integer value. Once it is Int then you can set it to your Number column.

```
 $web = get-spweb "http://servername/offices/Departments/IT/"
$list2 = $web.lists["list123"]
  foreach ($i in $list2.items)
 {
$a = $i["ID"]

 $sourceItem = $list2.items.GetItemById($a)

$calculatedfield = $sourceItem.Fields["CalcualtedNumericColumn"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCalculated];            
$c = [int]$calculatedfield.GetFieldValueAsText($sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"])
$sourceItem["NormalNumericColumn"] = $c 
$sourceItem.update();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..now in my case the column i want to assign the value to and the calculated column are of type number with automatic number of decimals... so i need to use `[double]` instead of `[int]` ?is this correct?

Comment: now this `$calculatedfield.GetFieldValueAsText($sourceItem["CalcualtedNumericColumn"])` will raise the following error "you not call the method on a null-valued expression.."